# Is there a way to have a template do specific things based on if parameter is a template type and value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I would like to have a helper function or a templated struct do different things if passed a function pointer or a functor, but if I understand the template system correctly, this is not possible, since one is a type and the other is not.

Am I correct on that?  I'd like to keep my API the same if possible, passing it either a functor or function pointer but not incur the cost of storing a pointer if not needed.  E.g.:

```
template <typename T, void(*fn)(T)>
struct X1
{
  T m_t;

  X(T t) : m_t(t) {}
  void invoke() { fn(m_t); }
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct X2
{
  T m_t;
  F m_f;

  X(T t, F f) : m_t(t), m_f(f) {}
  void invoke() { m_f(m_t); }
};
```

So in that case, I'd either like to have these structs sharing the same name, or have helper functions instantiate the appropriate struct with either a functor or a function pointer placed at the same parameter position with the same decorations around the function/functor.

Something like:

```
void fn(int) {}
auto functor = [](int){};
int h = 3;

auto x1 = make_X(h, fn);
auto x2 = make_X(h, functor);
```

Where `make_X()` is the link that I'm looking for.  Ideas?

Comment: Neither a function pointer nor a functor are types; they are both objects of types.

Comment: @Puppy But a function pointer can be a non-type template parameter, as in X1, while a functor cannot.

Comment: @Puppy, ok, my terminology might be incorrect. When I say function pointer, I do not mean the type of the function pointer but the value of the function pointer.  If you wish, tell me what would be the correct words I would use.  This is the reason that I included examples.

Comment: So you would like to specialize on types that are convertible to a function pointer?

Comment: I'd like to specialize in such a way that the size of the struct can remain small as possible by retaining the function pointer as part of the type definition so that it can be used later.  But if not convertible to a function pointer due to it having state, to save the information as part of the object.

Comment: @Adrian: A functor may be stateless, and so doesn't require to keep instance as member.() and it is not necessary convertible to function pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42, it is my understanding that a lambda function that has no state may be converted to a function pointer as part of the optimization system.  In any case, _may be_ and _not necessary_ are the operative words that state that it also could.

Answer (score 2):

The single responsibility principle says that the optimization around function pointers being stateless, and the rest of your code, should be handled separately.

So, create a stateless functor that calls `fn` in one part of your code:

```
template<class Sig, Sig* fn>
auto stateless() {
  return [](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto){
    return fn(decltype(args)(args)...);
  };
}
```

this is C++14.  In C++11, you just have to write the equivalent of that lambda manually.<sup>1</sup>

empty base optimization helper makes storing empty instances of types cheap and somewhat easy:

```
template<class Tag, class T, class=void>
struct ebo {
  ebo( T tin ):t(std::forward<T>(tin)) {}
  T t;
  T& get( Tag ){ return t; }
  T const& get( Tag ) const { return t; }
  ebo(ebo&&)=default;
  ebo(ebo const&)=default;
  ebo&operator=(ebo&&)=default;
  ebo&operator=(ebo const&)=default;
  ebo()=default;
};
template<class Tag, class T>
struct ebo<Tag, T,
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_empty<T>{} && !std::is_final<T>{}>
>:
  T
{
  ebo( T tin ):T(std::forward<T>(tin)) {}
  T& get( Tag ){ return *this; }
  T const& get( Tag ) const { return *this; }
  ebo(ebo&&)=default;
  ebo(ebo const&)=default;
  ebo&operator=(ebo&&)=default;
  ebo&operator=(ebo const&)=default;
  ebo()=default;
};
```

And implement `X` with the above:

```
struct F_tag {};
template <typename T, typename F>
struct X:ebo<F_tag, F>
{
  X(T tin, F fin):
    ebo<F_tag,F>(std::forward<F>(fin)),
    m_t(std::forward<T>(tin))
 {}

  T m_t;
  void invoke() { this->get(F_tag{})(m_t); }
};
template<class T, class F>
X<T,F> make_X( T t, F f ) {
  return {std::forward<T>(t),std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

At point of use, this looks like:

```
void fn(int) {}
auto functor = [](int){};
int h = 3;

auto x1 = make_X(h, stateless<void(int),&fn>());
auto x2 = make_X(h, functor);
```

zero bytes are used to store either the `fn(int)` or `functor`.

I take by value: adding forwarding references is left as an exercise.

---

<sup>1</sup> C++11 version of `stateless`:

```
template<class Sig, Sig* fn>
struct stateless_t {
  template<class...Ts>
  auto operator()(Ts&&...ts)const
  -> decltype( fn(std::declval<Ts>()...) )
  { return fn(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }
};
template<class Sig, Sig* fn>
stateless_t<Sig, fn> stateless() { return {}; }
```

Comment: Interesting.  Are you're missing `...` for your stateless return?  I'm not familiar with that syntax as it is c++14 and I marked this question as c++11.  What is the purpose of `Tag` and `F_tag`?

Comment: @Adrian piotr fixed the typo.  C++11 version of `stateless` added as a footnote.  They are very nearly equivalent.  I write things in C++14 when the equivalent C++11 is basically the same, because brevity is the soul of something or other, and C++14 is far more brevitious.

Comment: And what is the reason for the Tag types?

Comment: @Adrian it allows two different `ebo` classes storing the same type to be accessed/exist in the class that inherits from both of them.  Note that storing two instances of the same type may incur a byte of overhead (due to unique-addressing restrictions of the standard) even with different tags.

Comment: Man, can't wait till the committee fixes the deduction of types from constants. o.O

Comment: Is it possible to do this such that both `make_X` calls look the same?  This doesn't help so much if it doesn't.

Comment: @adrian no: for a function pointer catching function to be stateless, the pointer must be a template parameter.  For a stateless lambda, it cannot be.  And the two look different.